# Зацикленность алгоритма машины Поста

Tags: алгоритм

Столкнулся с проблемой проверки алгоритма на зацикленность. Помимо завершения успешной работы и достижения невыполнимой команды возможен случай когда алгоритм зацикливается (картека уходит бесконечно вбок или двигается по кругу). Сама реализация машины работает в режиме реального времени, команды срабатывают через определнный интервал времени. Хочу узнать какой способ проверки наиболее подходящий? На уме два варианта - находить последовательность повторяющихся команд и проверять что команды проходятся по тем же ячейкам. Либо же создать второй экземпляр машины без таймера, который запускается параллельно. И через определённое время, пропорциональное количеству команд, выдавать тревожный звоночек если работа машины до сих пор не закончена. Может есть более простой подход, о котором я на догадываюсь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно уверенно во всех случаях определять что машина Поста зациклилась из-за [проблемы остановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), которая, как известно, алгоритмически не разрешима. Хотя сама проблема сформулирована для машины Тьюринга, она также верна и для машины Поста.